# Can we reconstruct the hidden (latent) variables after executing EM?

Tags: stochastic-processes, latent-variable, expectation-maximization

The question is in the title. I know that EM algorithm could do maximum likelihood estimation  for models that have latent variables. I would like to know can we get the (estimated) value of these latent variables once the algorithm is finished ?

I know the question is vague and it depends on problems so I try to describe mine as follow: I have a random point process (failure process) with ${T_i}_{ \lbrace i \geq 0 \rbrace}$ denote the failure times. At each failure we have a flag $Z_i \sim \mathcal{B}(p)$, where $\mathcal{B}(p)$ is a Bernoulli distribution, to indicate the realized action, though in the end we can not observe $Z_i$ but only $T_i$. I might note that $T_i$ is not iid because it depends on the realized action at $T_i$ to jump from $T_i$ to $T_{i+1}$. With the help of EM algorithm, I can estimate $p$ and others parameters BUT I couldn't know the value (or estimated) of  $Z_i$ since this algorithm don't mention. So I would like to know if there are any articles discuss this one?

Any idea is welcome and thanks in advance !